# How to get the current active element in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I am trying to use a if statement to determine which button/textbox is submitted.

For example In firefox/IE/Opera, the following code can always return true when I click the button labeled submitNameSearch as id;

```
$(document.activeElement)[0] === $("#submitNameSearch")[0]
```

However, when I test my code in chrome/safari, the return value is false.

May I ask if I did anything wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's triggered on a click, why don't you just do:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    if (this.id=='submitNameSearch') {
        //do something
    }
});
```

and to see what element had focus before the focus was shifted to the clicked button you can always do :

```
var activeElm = null;

$('button').on({
    mousedown: function() {
        activeElm = document.activeElement;
    },
    click: function() {
        if (activeElm&&aciveElm.id=='submitNameSearch') {
             activeElm.focus; //returns focus
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is not only trigger by a click, for example, when user types enter in a textbox.

Comment: I don't get it? When a user hits enter in a text input of some sort, the element that has focus surely is the same element as where the enter key was pressed ?

Comment: Oh I get it, sorry for the confusion, yes enter in an input box indeed has the expected behavior, but may I ask why comparison doesn't work? It would be a lot nicer if i can put both input box and submit button handler together instead of in separate functions.

Comment: The comparison probably works just fine, the problem probably is that by the time you're comparing elements the focus has already shifted to whatever you clicked, and the active element is'nt what you think it is. A workaround is to use mousedown instead of click.